# Global setting for sample with replacement in R Studio?

Tags: r

I'm taking an analytics class, and I have been saving my workspace for the last couple of weeks. If I run the following code with the workspace open, I get the same results regardless of how replace is set

```
> set.seed(777)
> random.rows.train <- sample(1:nrow(ozone.data), 0.8*nrow(ozone.data), replace=F)
> length(random.rows.train)
[1] 88

> random.rows.test <- setdiff(1:nrow(ozone.data),random.rows.train)

> length(random.rows.test )

[1] 52
```

If I run the code w/o that workspace I get 52 for replace = T and 23 for replace = F, so it seems like there's something I unintentionally set in that workspace. Is this the case, and how do I see what else might be set? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps because you are setting the seed?

Comment: The size of the sample is controlled by the second parameter of the call to `sample`, in your case `0.8*nrow(ozone.data)`. I guess the difference between the two situations is in the size of ozone.data, whatever that is.